# ASP.NET MVC using form data inputs to create xml

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view with multiple text boxes, checkboxes and a submit button. On clicking submit the data needs to be passed to the DataController which will create Model object and serialize the object to xml. How should I pass all this data to the controller? This is what I have till now.

Data.cshtml

```
<legend>Enter Categories</legend>   
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-pull">
        Name:
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push">
        <input id="NameTextBox" type="text" placeholder="Enter a name ..." class="form-control" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="row event-selection">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="Data1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FirstName1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="Data2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="LastName1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="Data3" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FirstName2" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="Data4" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="LastName2" />
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="row">
    <button class="btn"><img src="~/Content/Images/Add.PNG" /></button>
    Add new category
</div>

<br />
<br />

<legend>Select Class</legend>
<div>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        Primary
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        Secondary
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        High
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        Low
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        B
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        G
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        P
    </label>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<legend>Select Area</legend>
<select class="dropdown" id="AreaDropDown">
    <option class="dropdown-header">Select a area ...</option>
</select>

<br />
<br />

<legend>Download</legend>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Download Data" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Download", "Data")'" />
```

DataController.cs

```
public class DataController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Download() // How should the form data get passed into this?
    {

        // Create objects using form data passed

        return new XmlResult<DataModel.XmlData>()
        {
            Data = dataModelInstance
        };
    }
}
```

DataModel.cs

```
public class DataModel
{
    [XmlRoot("Root")]
    public class Person
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public Name Name { get; set; }
    }

    [SerializableAttribute()]
    public class Name
    {
        [XmlElement("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an addition object / View Model and use that for your form / controller mapping. You can then populate your various XML objects You will need to assign `name` attributes to your various form tags to complete the mapping.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Name Name { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class DataController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Download(MyViewModel myViewModel)
    {
        ...
    }
}

<legend>Enter Categories</legend>   
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-pull">
        Name:
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push">
        <input id="NameTextBox" type="text" name="Name" ... />
    </div>
</div>
```

It is not clear from your question if you need additional help creating the XML or just the form / controller mapping?

Comment: This is the first area I am looking for help. I have some idea for generating xml, but I will post a separate question on that. I tried your solution and now when I click the Submit button I get 404 since now Data/Download doesn't exist. I the onclick event I call onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Download", "Data")'. So seems like the MyViewModel object needs to be passed in as well?

Comment: I read that I cannot post form data with location.href which is what I was using on my submit button. What would be an alternative?

Comment: Yes, `location.href` results in a `GET` request. Instead, you will need to wrap your form elements with a `<form method="post">` tag. You can use the MVC Helpers to format this but they are not necessary. You can also use the jQuery post() method but that may be complicating matters.